# Wordpress Menu Keeps Loading Behind Content. Z-Index not working

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Any tips on what could be wrong. The dropdown menu keeps loading behind everything, images, headers, etc.

So far I have added the z-index to all of the menu sections I assumed it could be. So far, nothing! Driving me nuts.

The theme I'm using is from wpstackable if that helps you out.

Thank you for any tips you can provide. This is really frustrating.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Main Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-menu {
    display: none;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.site-menu.toggled-on {
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.main-navigation .primary-menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.main-navigation ul {
    color: #f3f3f3;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.main-navigation.toggled-on ul,
.main-navigation.toggled-on ul.toggled-on {
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation.toggled-on ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
    margin-right: 3.5em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    color: var(--s-primary-color);
    content: "\f431";
    display: none;
    font-family: Genericons;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    right: 0.75em;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation li {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation a {
    color: #2c313f;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.75em 0;
}

.main-navigation a:focus,
.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: var(--s-primary-color);
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    z-index: 9999;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 896px) {
    .main-navigation ul ul {
        background: transparent;
    }   
}

.main-navigation .primary-menu .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .primary-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .primary-menu .current_page_ancestor > a {
    border-color: var(--s-primary-color);
}

/* Menu Toggle */
.menu-toggle {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}

/* Dropdown Toggle */
.dropdown-toggle {
    border: 0.25em solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 0.25em;
    width: 2.5em;
}

.dropdown-toggle:before {
    content: "\f431";
    font-family: Genericons;
    height: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 1em;
}

.dropdown-toggle.toggled-on:before {
    content: "\f432";
}
```

Comment: it would be a lot easier to sort out if you linked to a page where the problem appears.